# What is "Subtype mark required in this context" exactly?

Tags: ada

I get `Subtype mark required in this context` at `(*)`. What exactly is subtype mask and why is it complaining here?

main.adb

```
(*)Open_Route : Route(1..3) := (others => new Location(X=>1.0,Y=>1.0, id=>1));
--     Closed_Route : Route (Open_Route'First .. Open_Route'Last + 1);
--     P1 : Population (1..2);
```

Location.ads package spec

```
    type Location is record
      Id : Positive;
      X : Float;
      Y : Float;
   end record;
   type Location_Acess is access all Location; 
   type Route is array (Positive range<>) of Location_Acess; 
   type Route_Acess is access all Route;
   type Population is array (Positive range<>) of Route_Acess;
```

Comment: Add a single quote mark after `Location`: `new Location'(X=>1.0,Y=>1.0, id=>1)`.  And I'm sure the error message said "subtype mark", not "subtype mask".

Comment: @ajb - “mask" - me too, so I edited it for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *subtype_mark* is basically a name that denotes a type or subtype ([ARM 3.2.2(4)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-2-2.html#p4)). The reason why the ARM uses *subtype_mark* throughout is to do with some arcane distinction ([ARM 3.2.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-2-1.html)); when you say `type Foo is` you are declaring both a type and its *first subtype*, and the name `Foo` refers to the first subtype.

I think your problem is that you have a package `Location` *containing an entity of the same name*, and that this has confused the compiler.

You haven’t supplied a complete compilable code example, but reading between the lines I think it’d be something like this, after applying @ajb’s suggestion:

```ada
package Location is
   type Location is record
      Id : Positive;
      X : Float;
      Y : Float;
   end record;
   type Location_Acess is access all Location;
   type Route is array (Positive range<>) of Location_Acess;
   type Route_Acess is access all Route;
   type Population is array (Positive range<>) of Route_Acess;
end Location;
```

```ada
with Location; use Location;
package Location_User is
   Open_Route : Route(1..3) := (others => new Location'(X=>1.0,Y=>1.0, id=>1));
end Location_User;
```

and the compiler error message would be

```
location_user.ads:3:47: subtype mark required in this context
location_user.ads:3:47: found "Location" declared at location.ads:1
```

(see how it’s telling you to look at line 1 of `location.ads`, the package name?)

You *could* work round this by saying `new Location.Location`, but then you’d need to say it everywhere.

There are two canonical solutions, and there is a religious divide between the supporters of the two camps.

The first (my preferred one) would be to call the package `Locations` and leave the types `Location`, `Route`, `Population` as they are.

The second (which *I* consider ugly and would only use in dire need) would be to decorate type names with a suffix:

```ada
type Location_Type is
```

or

```ada
type Location_T is
```

Comment: I have to add that I’ve been quite happy in the past with decorating access types with `_P` and generics with `_G`. I said it was a religious issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time Simon. It was great and solved my problem.

Comment: @SimonWright, you forgot one naming strategy (from the Ada 95 Quality and Style Guide): Name the package `Location` and the type `Instance` (or `Object`). - That's what I do in most cases.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, I have done this where the package corresponds to something like a UML class, e.g. Person, Manager (and I have a code generator to prove it!). But `Location` doesn’t feel the same; you could have two `Location` values with the same attribute values and they would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The source code given in the question is not complete (you did not state whether you **use**d or merely **with**ed the *Location* package. I assume the latter since (at least with the compiler I have installed) the error message given is *invalid constraint: type has no discriminant*.

@ajb has already pointed out the solution to that problem: without the quote mark, the compiler looks for a type with a discriminant (a type parameterised by another type), but Location does not have a discriminant.

Moreover, unless you **use**d the Location package, `new Location` does not actually refer to a type (or subtype), but to a *package*. If you do not want to **use** Location, type 
`new Location.Location'(…` here. One way to avoid such errors (and get better error messages) is to use different names for packages and type: when both have the same name, it is not always intuitively clear how the compiler interprets the occurrence of the name, and when the opinions of compiler and programmer differ, confusion ensues.
 Personally, I like to use the plural for for the package, so in this case, there would be a package *Locations* containing the type *Location*, but there are other possibilities.