# Ada "Subtype mark required"

Tags: visibility, ada, required, subtype

I was given a project at uni where I need to write an ADA package of a graph. The points of the graph are stored in an array, the edges are stored in a matrix.(In the matrix if there is an edge between two points the number at that index is the weight/length of the edge)

The two procedures needed are NewPoint and NewEdge.

The three functions needed are IsItaPoint, IsitAnEdge, and print (the matrix and array).

I started learning ADA a week ago and I'm sure this is a 2 minute code for some of you. 
I wrote this:

Graph.ads

```
package Graph is 
function IsItAPoint (G: Graph;I: Integer) return Boolean;
function IsItAnEdge (G: Graph;I: Integer; J: Integer ) return Boolean;


procedure NewEdge (G: Graph;I: Integer; J: Integer; S: Integer); 
procedure NewPoint(G: Graph;I: Integer);


type PointArray is array(Integer range <>) Of Integer;
type EdgeMatrix is array(Integer range <>,
                    Integer range <>) of INTEGER;
PointCount: Integer:=0;


end Graph;
```

Graph.adb

```
package body Graph is

procedure NewPoint(G: Graph;I: Integer) is
begin
    G.PointCount:=G.PointCount+1;
    G.PointArray(G.PointCount):=I;
end;

procedure NewEdge(G: Graph;I: Integer; J: Integer; S: Integer) is
begin
    G.EdgeMatrix(I,J):=S;
end;

function IsItAPoint (G: Graph;I: Integer) return Boolean is 
begin
    for J in 1..100 loop
        if (G.PointArray(J)=I) then return True; end if;
    end loop;
    return False;
end;


function IsItAnEdge (G: Graph;I: Integer; J: Integer ) return Boolean is
begin
    return (G.EdgeMatrix(I,J)=Null);
end;

end Graph;
```

I get "Graf is not visable" and "subtype mark required in this context" error in the adb file.

Can you help me fix this whole thing?

Comment: You presumably have a type (or subtype) called "Graph" declared somewhere else, presumably in another package, yes? Add that package spec to the Q. Also, leaving aside the wisdom of re-using the type name for the package, it would be useful to indicate which line in `graph,adb` reports the error. My guess is that the type declaration for "Graph" is simply not visible because there is no With or Use clause for that package.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28557589/40851) for ‘subtype mark required’. Also, I’d recommend calling the package `Graphs`; then you can add the missing `type Graph is ...` without confusion.

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question. I presume the actual message was "Graph is not visible", not "Graf is not visable". Minor spelling errors like this can be very significant.

Answer (score 4):

OK, looking at the code so far, I think you may be mistaking a `Package` as a replacement for a C++ `Class`, whereas it's really more like a C++ `Namespace`.

C++ didn't have namespaces when I first used it but they are such a good organising principle that it tacked them on later. In contrast, packages were an original part of Ada.

Now a C++ `Class` (or `Struct`, or `Union`) would map onto an Ada `Record`. If it stands alone it can be a simple record, but if it's intended to be inheritable, it'll be a `Tagged Record`. Tagged Record, allowing inheritance, wasn't part of Ada-83, it was added 20 years ago in Ada-95.

And typical practice would be to wrap the `Record` and all its externally visible operations in a `Package`.

So I think you're looking for something like:

```ada
package Graph_Pkg is 

type Graph is tagged private; -- hide everything about the actual record!

function IsItAPoint (G: Graph;I: Integer) return Boolean;
function IsItAnEdge (G: Graph;I: Integer; J: Integer ) return Boolean;

procedure NewEdge (G: in out Graph;I: Integer; J: Integer; S: Integer); 
procedure NewPoint(G: in out Graph;I: Integer);

-- PointCount: Integer:=0; -- moved to package body
function PointCount return Integer;

private
-- Everything below here is hidden from package users

type PointArray is array(Integer range <>) Of Integer;
type EdgeMatrix is array(Integer range <>,
                    Integer range <>) of INTEGER;

type Graph is tagged record
   -- here the member variables are declared
   Points : PointArray;
end record;

end Graph_Pkg;
```

Now all the implementation details belong in the body.

```ada
package body Graph_Pkg is

-- The equivalent of C++ "static members" can be declared here
PointCount: Integer:=0;

-- and add the subprogram implementations here

end Graph_Pkg;
```

If you want the number of points in a graph to be variable after the graph has been constructed, I can see problems ahead in the implementation. You might want to look at Ada-2005 Container classes for that.

Comment: Brian, that was an obvious change - also, I think `Graph` needs to contain an `EdgeMatrix`, to be constrained by the (maximum number?) of points and edges, and to contain the current number of points and edges.

Comment: I'm sure it does need to contain an EdgeMatrix, I just wanted to point in the right way to organise things. And I didn't want to get into the details of sizing the matrices, though from what I can see of the design they are probably best implemented using the container classes. Otherwise there's a sharp learning curve involving either discriminated records or access types ahead...