# Subtype Mark Required in this context - Ada

Tags: vector, primes, ada

I'm working to implement a prime decomposition function in Ada. I need to return a Vector from `calc_prime_numbers`. I'm trying to store that vector in `Y`. However, whenever I compile, the compiler is saying `prime.adb:40:07: subtype mark required in this context`. I'm not sure what that means. What does subtype required mean? How do I fix it?

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Containers.Vectors;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Containers;

procedure Prime is
   package Integer_Vectors is new Vectors(Natural, Integer);

   function Is_Prime(I : Integer) return Boolean is
      J : Integer := 2;
   begin
      for J in 2 .. I-1 loop
         if I mod J = 0 then
            return False;
         end if;
      end loop;
      return True;
   end Is_Prime;

   function calc_prime_numbers(n : Integer) return Integer_Vectors.Vector is
      i : Integer := 0;
      m : Integer;
      Numbers : Integer_Vectors.Vector;
   begin
      m := n + 1;
      while (true) loop
         i:=i + 1;
         if Is_Prime(i) then
            Integer_Vectors.Append(Numbers, i);
            Put(Integer'Image(i) & " + ");
         end if;
         if i = m then
            exit;
         end if;
      end loop;
      New_Line;
      return Numbers;
   end calc_prime_numbers;

   X : Integer;
   Y : Integer_Vectors; — line 40

begin
   while (true) loop
      Get(X);
      if Is_Prime(X) then
         Put(Integer'Image(X) & " is prime.");
      else
         Put(Integer'Image(X) & " is not prime.");
      end if;
      New_Line;
      Y := calc_prime_numbers(X); — line 40

   end loop;
end Prime;
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `while (true) loop` is the same as `loop`, and `if i = m then exit; end if;`is the same as `exit when i = m;`

Comment: Integer_Vectors is the name of a package. That package exports a type, and you want to use the name of that type - NOT the package - in Y's declaration. (Looking at the documentation for the generic package will reveal the name of the type...)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28557589/40851) for stuff on 'subtype mark required'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line number in the error message don't match the code you pasted, and you don't indicate where line 40 is, so I'll have to guess:

you instantiate a package called `Integer_Vectors`. Later you declare a variable `Y : Integer_Vectors;`. So the compiler complains because it expects a type for the variable whereas you provided the name of a package.

Comment: I have updated the original post to indicate line 40. How can I fix this? Would this be the solution? `subtype Integer_Vectors is Vectors(Natural, Integer);`

Comment: How about using the `Vector` type in the generic package, like you are already doing inside the `calc_prime_numbers` function: `Numbers : Integer_Vectors.Vector;`